# Get multiple images to adjust to browser size with unknown image sizes

Tags: php, html, css, image, size

I have a little issue here I cant seem to solve.

I am making a website which shows uploaded images on a page (images are uploaded by users and are not the same size). But unfortunately it does not look good at all this way because it show the entire image and if 2 don't fit next to each other on the page the second one gets pushed down to a newline and leaves a huge gap next to image 1. What I want to accomplish is something like this [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/explore/).

How would I be able to accomplish this?

I have all the images inside a DIV name images and all the image DIVS are in the DIV inhoud

**HTML and PHP:**

```
<div id="inhoud">

            <?php 
            include('dbc.php');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images";
            $result = $dbc->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="image"><img src=<?php echo "uploads/".$row['link'] ?>></img><div class="info"><p><?php echo "By " . $row['user'] ?></p></div></div>
                    <?php 
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            $dbc->close();


            ?>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#inhoud{
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: grey;
padding-top: 100px;
}
.image{
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
}
.image img{
max-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: You'll need to get a JS plugin like Masonry or Isotope.

Comment: I agree with @austinthedeveloper. Here is a good website to start: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Comment: @austinthedeveloper Thank you! i am going to try to inplement Masonry now

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do it like Flickr--which keeps a set row height and has variables image widths--then you should be able to do that with CSS.

What you need to do is give the images a set height, and then set width to auto. So, if you want each row to have a height of say 20%:

```
#inhound {
  height:900px; /* if you want to use a percentage make sure its parent has a height */
}

.image img {
  height:20%;
  width:auto;
}
```

It's dependent on how exactly you want to display them, of course, but this is the basic principle.